# For a stochastic process $X(\cdot)$ which dominates another process $Y(\cdot)$. Does equal stationary expectation imply same stationary distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have two ergodic stochastic processes $X(\cdot)$ and $Y(\cdot)$ on $[0,\infty)$, i.e. they converge in law to some stationary distributions $X$ and $Y$ as $t\to\infty$. Suppose also that $X(t)$ (first order) stochastically dominates $Y(t)$ for each $t\geq0$. If $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY$, can we conclude that $X\stackrel d=Y$? This is an idea I got by working on a probability application, but I cannot see whether this is true or not. Any help or references are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_X^t$ be the distribution function of $X(t)$, $F_X^t$ the distribution function of $Y(t)$ and let $F_X^\infty$ and $F_Y^\infty$ be the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

We have for all $t$ that $F_Y^t \leq F_X^t$. Since $F_X^t\to F_X^\infty$ for all continuity points of $F_X^\infty$ and similarly $F_Y^t\to F_Y^\infty$ for all continuity points of $F_Y^\infty$, we obtain $$F_Y^\infty(s)=\lim_{t\to\infty}F_Y^t(s)\leq \lim_{t\to\infty}F_X^t(s)=F_X^\infty(s)$$ assuming $s$ is a continuity point of both $F_X^\infty$ and $F_Y^\infty$.

For simplicity, assume that both $F_X^\infty$ and $F_Y^\infty$ are continuous at almost every point. Since $X,Y\geq 0$ we get $$0=\mathbb EX-\mathbb EY = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X^\infty(s))ds - \int_0^\infty (1-F_Y^\infty(s))ds = \int_0^\infty F_Y^\infty(s)-F_X^\infty (s)ds.$$ Since the integrand is non-positive, we get that $F_X^\infty(s)=F_Y^\infty(s)$ for almost-every $s$.
Hence $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$.